# VMware vFabric Server timeout

Tags: spring, timeout, vmware

So, I have downloaded a Spring Tool Suite and when i want to start VMware vFabric tc Server i get this message :

> Server VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.6 was unable to start within 120 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

Could anyone tell me where can i change this parameter which will allow me to start the server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Servers view in Eclipse, double click on the Server name, that will open up an editor, there's a Timeouts section, increase the value for Start.