# Increase vfabric tc server startup time

Tags: tomcat, timeout, vmware, tcserver

I have installed vfabric-2.9.5-developer server on my machine and I have created stand-alone server instance using tcruntime-instance.bat and tcruntime-ctl.bat scripts. When I deploy war file on this instance, server runs out of time. I noticed this exception in the log file - unable to start within 120 seconds..

I know my application is heavy enterprise app and when we deploy it on tomcat, we usually increase the timeout using eclipse's server editor. But, I am not sure how do that manually on vFabric instance WITHOUT using server editor/ Hyperic.

The same question goes with heap size and PermGen size. Which conf file on vfabric instance I need change to increase the heap and PermGen size ? I tried changing it in wrapper.conf, but didn't make any difference.

here is the snippet from wrapper.conf that I tried changing heap and PermGen size in:

```
    # Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1="-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\common\endorsed"
wrapper.java.additional.2="-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%"
wrapper.java.additional.3="-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%"
wrapper.java.additional.4="-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp"
wrapper.java.additional.5="-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager"
wrapper.java.additional.6="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
wrapper.java.additional.7="-Dwrapper.dump.port=-1"
wrapper.java.additional.8="-Xss256K"
wrapper.java.additional.9="-Dinsight.devedition=true"
wrapper.java.additional.10="-Daspectj.overweaving=true"
wrapper.java.additional.11="-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.factory=default"
wrapper.java.additional.12="-Dinsight.base=%CATALINA_BASE%/insight"
wrapper.java.additional.13="-Dinsight.logs=%CATALINA_BASE%/logs"
wrapper.java.additional.14="-Xmx1024m"
wrapper.java.additional.15="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
wrapper.java.additional.16="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
wrapper.java.additional.17="-Dgemfire.disableShutdownHook=true"
wrapper.java.additional.18="-Dgemfire.ignoreMisses=true"
wrapper.java.additional.19="-javaagent:%CATALINA_BASE%/bin/insight-weaver-1.9.2.SR3.jar"
```

I am new with this server, therefore any help would much appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I have already checked these questions and don't not resolve my problem
[vmware-vfabric-server-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339597/vmware-vfabric-server-timeout)  and [vmware-vfabric-tc-server-wont-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838310/vmware-vfabric-tc-server-wont-start)

Updated: I was trying to reproduce the 120 seconds message but I am not seeing it anymore. This is what I captured so far:

```
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2928)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getResponseWrapperClass(RuntimeModeler.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:676)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:586)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:366)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace that contains the 120 seconds message?

Comment: How did you change the memory settings in wrapper.conf. Post the actual changes from the file.

Comment: Hm, that's the standard wrapper.conf, nothing changed regarding java.additional settings. Increase MaxPermSize to 512m and test again. If you get the 120 seconds exception post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Andrei Stefan - Thanks for your response. I changed the wrapper.conf and increased MaxPermSize. I am able to deploy the application now but I am running into another issue. I have almost 25-30 JAX-WS web services and I see that endpoints getting set successfully but I am not able to hit the WSDLs. I think some listener is not getting started.. my request for WSDL just hangs. How do I see what server is doing ? There are no exceptions in the wrapper /catalina log files.

Comment: I was able to resolve issue with WSDLs. Here is the problem and solution in case anybody run into the same problem:

Comment: I was able to resolve issue with WSDLs. Here is the problem and solution in case anybody run into the same problem: vFabric comes with two versions of Tomcat 6.0.x and 7.x. By default it uses highest available version when you create the instances. I didn't realize that before. My application is not compatible with 7.x version. Therefore, I created new instance explicitly with 6.0.x version and deployed app there. That resolved the WSDL issue !